# How do I convert $_POST to string then assign to a $variable? Wanna use it in SQL

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, variables, post

I don't know how to convert this $_POST to string and ASSIGN it to a variale rather than an array. Is there a Convert.ToString(RadioButtonValue) like in C#? I want to use the variable as a parameter in my SQL statement.

```
$DeptCode = $_POST['Department'];
        print_r($DeptCode);

        $sql = "SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpID, EmpName FROM EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmpID = EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION.EmpID AND EmpStatus='active' AND DeptCode = '$DeptCode'";
        $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        if($results != $sql)
        {
            die('Error' . mysql_error());
        }
```

This is my SQL statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpID, EmpName FROM EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmpID = EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION.EmpID AND EmpStatus='active' AND DeptCode = '$DeptCode'";
```

When I run it... it always show

```
Array ( [0] => PD ) Error
```

This is the whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Checkup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="http://localhost/clinic/InsertPatient.php">Insert Patient</a></h1><br>
    <h1><a href="http://localhost/clinic/InsertEmployee.php">Insert Doctor and Specialization</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="http://localhost/clinic/InsertProcedureHTML.php">Insert Products and Services</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="http://localhost/clinic/NewCheckup.php">New Checkup</a></h1>
    <form method="post">
        <?php
        //action="http://localhost/clinic/NewCheckup2.php"
            $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', "");
            if(!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }   
            mysql_select_db("db_clinic", $con) or die(mysql_error());
            $sql = "SELECT DeptCode, DeptName FROM DEPARTMENT";
            $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {                       
                echo "<input type='radio' name='Department[]' value='".$row['DeptCode']."'>".$row['DeptName'];
            }
            mysql_close($con);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', "");
        if(!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("db_clinic", $con) or die(mysql_error());

        $DeptCode = $_POST['Department'];
        print_r($DeptCode);
        echo $DeptCode;
        $sql = "SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpID, EmpName FROM EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmpID = EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION.EmpID AND EmpStatus='active' AND DeptCode = '$DeptCode'";
        $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);
        if($results != $sql)
        {
            die('Error' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_close($con);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: your `if($results != $sql)` condition is completely wrong. at least test to see if `$results !== false`

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2536029

Comment: SQL injections ftw ! :-)

Comment: what is  print out $DeptCode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use without brackets `[]` like this

```
name='Department'
```

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It's the only correct answer so far. Radio buttons within the same group need the same name, and so should not be an array as named by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array with the form input:

```
<input type='radio' name='Department[]' value='
                                    ^^
                                    ||
                     PHP HTML Form Variable Array Notation
```

This is also shown when you do the `print_r` for your debugging:

```
$DeptCode = $_POST['Department'];
print_r($DeptCode);

Array ( [0] => PD )
```

So either don't create an array or access it as an array.

To learn more about arrays in PHP in general, please see:

- http://php.net/array

To learn more about arrays in PHP Forms, please see:

- http://php.net/language.variables.external

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Variable variables for this purpose. A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. Eg:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
 $$key = $value; //create variable
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

just use this :

```
implode("", $DeptCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it will help you.

```
$post_string = json_encode($your_post_variable);
```

now you have the string value in $post_string.

also you can get post data values by

```
json_decode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$deptCode = $_POST['Department'];

$post_array = implode(" ", array_keys($deptCode));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($deptCode));
$newDeptCode = implode(" ", $escaped_values);
```

To use it in mysql statement:

```
//tokenize the string
$token = strtok($newDeptCode, " ");

while($token != FALSE){

   //your query statement
   mysql_query("SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpID, EmpName FROM EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmpID = EMPLOYEE_SPECIALIZATION.EmpID AND EmpStatus='active' AND DeptCode = '$token'");

   $token = strtok(" ");
}
```

I strongly suggest that you start using PDO though. Its safer